# Abort copy mode in Screen

Tags: gnu-screen

While using GNU Screen in copy mode, I sometimes want to abort in the middle and go back to the prompt. What command will exactly achieve that ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to use the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. At least, that is what I use to get out of copy mode in screen.

There are many alternative strategies as well, including hitting <kbd>q</kbd>, or hitting the <kbd>Return</kbd> key twice.

Comment: The `Return` is dangerous. I had a bad experience while doing a distupgrade. It did exit copy mode, but did it also answering an apt-get question about keeping an old file configuration. So, I would prefer a `control-a` combination to exit copy mode. Any more robust suggestions?